# Не работает ProgressBar

Tags: java, android

Не работает `ProgressDialog` в асинхронной задаче. Ошибок никаких, просто не отображается:

```
class ProgressDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    ProgressDialog PD;
    Downloader dow = new Downloader();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        PD.show(getApplicationContext(), null, "Loading Please Wait...", true);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
    {
        dow.downloadFile(arg0[0], arg0[1]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        PD.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: где `ProgressDialog PD = new ProgressDialog();`

Comment: @Saidolim пробовал, всё равно не работает... Закачка работает нормально, а вот ProgressDialog не работает!

Comment: тогда поставте этот прогресбар в layout и тут его просто через id используйте. точно будет работать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У меня работает так :

```
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Загрузка Подождите...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();  // открываем диалог

    }
     @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
             //Что то делаем, например запрос JSON
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            pDialog.dismiss(); // Закрываем диалог
    }
```

Comment: Отлично.. Спасибо, у меня тоже заработал. Только остался один момент, после окончания загрузки диалог не закрывается...

Comment: Попробуйте проверить скорее всего не срабатывает onPostExecute()

Comment: да он её не видит, только судя по ошибкам то этой функции нету в самом интерфейсе...

Comment: Ошибку нашёл, Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Она есть в интерфейсе. Когда запускаешь асинхронный поток, изначально запускается функция   onPreExecute(), потом запускается основная функция doInBackground(), которая делает основную работу, при удачном завершении которой, запускается функция onPostExecute().  Одной из причин почему не срабатывает onPostExecute(), явлается неудачное завершение кода в функции doInBakcground(). попробуй порыскай в ней.

Comment: Понял, не успел добавить коммент вовремя

Comment: не в этом причина была, дело в том что надо было проставить типы в шаблоне правильно, и тогда всё начнёт нормально работать. Спасибо ещё раз.